# Apps Script To Delete Adjacent Cell Using CheckBox

Tags: checkbox

I am trying to delete contents in cell L3 of a google sheet when I untick the checkbox in K3

```
  function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = e.range;

  if (activeSheet.getName() == "Ranging Doc" && cell.getA1Notation() == "K3" && cell.isUnChecked()){
    activeSheet.getRange("L3").clearContent();
  }
  }
```

This is the script used so far, playing around with someone else's coding from another post but I cant seem to get it to work. I'm assuming it is to do with the **cell.isUnChecked()){** part of the code but unsure how to rewrite.

Any suggestive help would be appreciated